# getting ios 4 camera exposure data during live capture

Tags: iphone, camera, exif

Ive searched everywhere and havnt managed to find an answer to this question so I thought Id ask it here.

Im currently using the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to and CaptureOutput to get frames from the camera in real time at 30fps. I have left the default settings of autoexposure and auto focus etc.
I want to be able to query the camera per frame WITHOUT RESORTING TO THE STILL CAPTURE OPTION and ask what the cameras current frame exposure, aperture and focal length are.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the results of:

```
  CFDictionaryRef metadataDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, CFSTR("MetadataDictionary"), NULL);
```